# Searchkick / Rails working example with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, mongoid

I can't figure how to properly hook a view / form for searching through my docs with elasticsearch + mongoid.

My Searchkick config is working – I get the results inside the rails console. But I don't know exactly where to put things in what order in the controller/model/view to make it work. From the rails console I get the search results, docs are properly mapped and everything is fine.

I can't find a working example of an simple search form with searchkick including an working example of how a model, controller and a view should look like.

Anybody got an **working** example to checkout with Rails 4.1rc1 / Mongoid4 / Elasticsearch 1.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got rails 4.0.2, Mongoid4, and ElasticSearch >= 1

Anyway, this works for us in the controller:

```
class CropSearchesController < ApplicationController
  def search
    query = params[:q].to_s
    @crops = Crop.search(query,
                         limit: 25,
                         partial: true,
                         misspellings: {distance: 2},
                         fields: ['name^20',
                                  'common_names^10',
                                  'binomial_name^10',
                                  'description'],
                         boost_by: [:guides_count]
                         )
    if query.empty?
      @crops = Crop.search('*', limit: 25, boost_by: [:guides_count])
    end

    # Use the crop results to look-up guides
    crop_ids = @crops.map { |crop| crop.id }
    @guides = Guide.search('*', where: {crop_id: crop_ids})

    render :show
  end
end
```

And this is our model:

```
class Crop
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Slug
  searchkick

  field :guides_count, type: Fixnum, default: 0

  field :name
  field :common_names, type: Array
  validates_presence_of :name
  field :binomial_name
  field :description
  belongs_to :crop_data_source
  field :sun_requirements
  field :sowing_method
  field :spread, type: Integer
  field :row_spacing, type: Integer
  field :height, type: Integer

  embeds_many :pictures, cascade_callbacks: true, as: :photographic
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures

  def search_data
    as_json only: [:name, :common_names, :binomial_name, :description, :guides_count]
  end

  slug :name
end
```

And then you just accesses the @crops in the view like you would normally.

You can have a look at our source code on github: https://github.com/openfarmcc/OpenFarm

(Just stumbled across this question while looking for how to do the ordering, figured it out, but thought I'd just copy paste this here in case anyone finds this useful).